# How to write Spark streaming calculated results to HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am writing Spark streaming job and my batch window is 1 min. At regular intervals of 30 mins i want to write something to HDFS.

- Can i do that in Spark streaming ?
- If yes , How ?

I dont want to write in each Spark streaming batch as it will be too many files on HDFS.

I am getting input stream , I am adding only records which I have not seen earlier to RDD (or Dataframe) and then in the end after 30 mins interval i want to write that to HDFS.

The current solution in my mind is

1. Use updateStateByKey
2. Use Checkpoint with huge interval

Just wondering what the standard pattern is in such use cases.

Thanks,

Comment: SaveMode with append should help

Comment: It is rather and old method but i recommend using updatestatebykey. You can follow the strps in this link. http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/11/how-to-do-near-real-time-sessionization-with-spark-streaming-and-apache-hadoop/. I hope it helps